# How useful is the 160$ laptop/notebook?

Tags: laptop

I am going to Czech Republic in terms of Erasmus+ programme for 5 months.I haven't got any notebooks therefore I need it.I will study Information Technology.I've got lessons like Java Programming,Web Design,C etc.I searched out the Internet and I found a cheap notebook which I'll do programming.Is 2GB's of ram,Intel Celeron N3060 processor 1.6ghz(turbo boost 2.4) and 32 GB's of storage useful for my works?

Comment: This laptop will lag like crazy. Expect 5 minute boot times in a laptop like that and 1 minute logins. If you can't afford a better laptop it will perform fine, but you'll have to exercise your patience b/c it will by no means be snappy.

Comment: @adadion On the contrary, that's the definition of a technical support question of the kind that are explicitly off topic here. Also, don't use comments to answer questions.

Comment: @artofcode Sorry if I'm rude. `are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices.` . Well, while he post, he barely buy the notebook. So it is definitely about pre-purchase device. While technical support question is about having problem with hardware on his hand.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I am not looking for technical support,please look at topic and my task.It is definetely about hardware recommandation in pre-purchase,repeating again I am not looking for technical support,I had not said my computer,my device is not working.Please be little more understanding and you should not use imperative sentences to approach others.Thank you.

Comment: You're asking if X device will suit your needs. That falls under technical support / technical advice, which we don't do here.